# SQL query to get the first date of fixed length consecutive dates with positive balance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a data table with consecutive dates and each date has a positive or negative balance.

```
Date        Balance
--------------------
2021-01-01  100.00
2021-01-02   50.00
2021-01-03  -10.00
2021-01-04  100.00
2021-01-05  120.00
2021-01-06   90.00
2021-01-07  100.00
```

I need to find the first date that has three(3) consecutive positive balances, which is 2021-01-04 in this case.

How to implement it in SQL Server 2019

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lead()` and `min()`:

```
select min(date)
from (select t.*,
             lead(balance) over (order by date) as balance_1,
             lead(balance, 2) over (order by date) as balance_2
      from t
     ) t
where balance > 0 and balance_1 > 0 and balance_2 > 0;
```